# Can IPC::Open2 and Term::ReadKey be used together?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use Perl to run/communicate with other programs.  Although I have been able to use Open2 to receive the output from another program (and send input to it), I want a way to receive the output from the program one character at a time.

This is an example snippet of code that receives the output from another program:

```
use strict;
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2(my $read, my $write, "python test2.txt");
print $write "various words\n";
my $answer = <$read>;
print $answer;
```

This is an example code snippet that listens (but doesn't wait) for input, and it does other things until I press a button.

```
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $char = '';
my $hesitation = 0;
while($char eq ''){
 print "$hesitation\n";
 $hesitation++;  #other things here
 $char = ReadKey(-1);
}
print "You pressed the $char key!";
```

Although these are just examples, I want a way to combine this behavior.  I've tried to combine them like this:

```
use strict;
use Term::ReadKey;
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2(my $read, my $write, "python test2.txt");
print $write "various words\n";
my $char = '';
my $hesitation = 0;
while($char eq ''){
 print "$hesitation\n";
 $hesitation++;
 $char = ReadKey(-1,$read);
}
print "You pressed the $char key!";
```

The problem is that `ReadKey(-1,$read)` seems to be receiving input from STDIN as opposed to the output of `test2.py`.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  As far as I can see, no errors are being thrown.

I've seen that several features of ReadKey do not work on Windows (which I use), but I don't think this feature is one of them.  If this won't be able to work, are there any better alternatives which are still pretty simple to use?

Answer (score 0):

*Term*::ReadKey interacts with the *term*inal.

Sounds like you're looking for a non-blocking read.

```
use IO::Handle qw( );        # Not needed on new versions of Perl.
use IPC::Open2 qw( open2 );

my $pid = open2(
   local *FR_CHILD,
   local *TO_CHILD,
   'perl', '-e', 'sleep 1; print qq{a\n}',
);

FR_CHILD->blocking(0);

print TO_CHILD "various words\n";

my ($char, $hesitation);
while (!defined($char = getc(FR_CHILD))) {
   print "$hesitation\n";
   ++$hesitation;
}

print "Read \"$char\"\n";

close(TO_CHILD);
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Output:

```
...
15485
15486
15487
15488
15489
15490
Read "a"
```

`->blocking(0)` doesn't work for me on Windows, though, and I had to use `'perl -e"sleep 1; print "a\n"'`

Comment: Used type globs because IPC::Open[23] has at least one problem with lexical handles.